# Analytics for Single Page JavaScript Webapps (Google Analytics?)

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, analytics

Can Google Analytics be used for tracking user behavior in a single page web application? I have used Google Analytics for typical websites but haven't used it for these type of web apps.

If not Google Analytics, are there other tools that can be used? I believe some sort of custom tracking will need to be setup for user interactions?

Answer (score 5):

Google Analytics can be used with single page applications. You can either use [Events](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) to track user behaviour, or you can register "virtual" page views in the same way that real pages get recorded in a multi-page site.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested in achieving the same with Piwik read here:

http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/#toc-manually-trigger-a-page-view-on-click-or-on-js-event

What you basically have to do is simply triggering a page view manually whenever it is appropriate.

```
piwikTracker.trackPageView('Current/Path/Or/Any/Name');
```